# How to solve 'Cannot read property 'bootstrap' of null' in angular 12?

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap, angular12

I am trying to run an angular project in angular 12 which was built on angular 6. I successfully build the project but it showing the following error in the console,

```
'Cannot read property 'bootstrap' of null'
```

I have tried many solutions but none of them are working. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you ever figured it out what the solution was? I have the same error after updating to angular v12

Comment: I downgraded the angular version from 12 to 10. Thats how I solved the problem for now.